# Bash Script_ Inserting variable read from read command into command

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sh

I am working on a project using the BLS API.
Reference:  http://www.bls.gov/developers/api_unix.htm

My current script follows:

```
declare  id=""
echo -n "Enter id: "
read id
echo -n "enter startyear: "
read startyear
echo -n "enter endyear: "
read endyear


curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"seriesid":      ["$id"], "startyear":'$startyear' , "endyear":'$endyear'}' http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/
```

I have edited it and put in the ID by hand like on the reference page and that worked.  I cannot seem to read the $id from input and insert it into the curl command.  Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated thank you.

edit1:

I updated the code and changed the quotes for the {} for the -d option to double quotes and the same error persists.

edit2:

after updating the file with the code provided in the comments I receive a:

```
Warning:  You can only select one HTTP request!
```

when I run it.

Comment: The variable `$id` is not being expanded because it is inside single quotes.

Comment: I just updated it and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Your 2nd edit suggests you're doing `-I` instead of `-i`.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code snippet into a new file and it worked.  If I want to read up on why where would you suggest I go?

Comment: As I said above, the warning from curl suggested that you were using `-I` (make a HEAD request) rather than `-i` (include response headers). An HTTP request cannot be both a HEAD request and a POST request.

Comment: Thank you.  One last thing what do the backslashes do?

Comment: They escape the following double quotes so that they don't cause the string to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear up any confusion in my comment above, the following should work:

```
echo -n "Enter id: "
read id
echo -n "enter startyear: "
read startyear
echo -n "enter endyear: "
read endyear

curl -i \
     -X POST \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d "{\"seriesid\":[\"${id}\"],\"startyear\":\"${startyear}\",\"endyear\":\"${endyear}\"}" \
     http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your -d argument is surrounded by `'` single quotes which dont allow variable interpolation. Use double quotes `"args $id "`